# Pytest DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>

Tags: python, flask, pytest

When unit testing an except I am getting an error that it did not raise. Not sure where it is going wrong.

The code being tested:

```
@bp.route("/contact/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def contact_details():
    if request.form:
        contacts = contact(username=request.form.get("username"), email=request.form.get("email"),details=request.form.get("details"))
        try:
            db.session.add(contacts)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Your query has been raised successfully.")
            return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
        except:
            flash("There has been an issue trying to raise a contact ticket.")
            return render_template("main/home.html")
    return render_template("main/contact.html")
```

Pytest:

```
def test_contact_ticket_error(client):
    client.post('/register', data={"username": "tester1", "password": "password"}, follow_redirects =True)
    client.post('/', data={"username": "tester1", "password": "password"}, follow_redirects = True)

    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        response = client.post("/contact/", data = {"username":"tester1","email":"tester@gmail.com","details":"testing contact"})
    assert b'There has been an issue trying to raise a contact ticket.' in response.data
```

Need advise on how to resolve this issue so test passes.

Comment: Why do you think it should raise an exception?

Comment: Your function doesn't raise an exception - it catches an exception it receives, and returns a value. So the calling code sees no exception and the pytest assertion behaves as it should.

Comment: An exception was raised *in* your function, but not *by* your function: you caught the exception and handled it internally. Your test needs to check if `redirect` or `render_template` was called.

Answer (score -1):

Your function handles the error and it wouldn't know that you handled it.
Try making it return a success code here's an example (i don't know how to check it)

```
try:
   # do the thing
   done = True
except:
   done = False
return done
```

Comment: The user doesn't have control over what the `post` method returns, as it's generated the framework; nor does the user have freedom in defining what `contact_details` returns, as it has to return something expected by the framework that actually calls it.